# Steps for building app to production in extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

[image: Loading time of app.js]I have used "sencha app refresh" and "sencha app build production" commands which generates classes-app.js file. Whether this file is sufficient to move my app to production.The file size is 800kb. Any other steps to be follow for production.

Comment: Have you read Sencha's oficial tutorial about it ?

Comment: @code4jhon Yeah i read the documentation. but still i am not clear. Just these 2 command helps to build app for production ???http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command_app_ext41

Comment: @code4jhon If you are well good in taking production build. Can u share your idea so it will be good help